# Best statistical test to run for two cohorts, each of whose subjects received ordinal assessment scores

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a question regarding the statistical test I should run for my data. Basically, there are two cohorts of patients — treatment and control — and for each cohort, each patient was assessed for discomfort on a 0-10 scale, for up to 7 days, though some patients did not receive that many assessments. I want to somehow do an overall comparison between these two cohorts, with my alternative hypothesis being that discomfort overall decreased in the treatment cohort.

Based on the reading I've done, it seems that I should use a mixed ANOVA, though I'm not entirely sure how I should go about this (or if this is indeed the test to use). N > 100 for both samples. I'm using R.

Comment: What are you trying to assess? Average amount of pain per subject over the "up to" 7 days. Is that decrease in pain level from beginning to end, no matter how many days? If there is a clear-cut difference score for each patient, then you have a two-sample test (on those differences)---not an ANOVA. Probably a 2-sample Welch t test or a 2-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test. I'd have to look at some data to know which.

Comment: @BruceET I wanted to just have some way to compare the overall differences in pain between the 2 cohorts, such that I could potentially day that the treatment cohort overall felt less pain (so no, not change in pain fr day 1 to day 7). And since the mean of Likert data doesn't parallel a distinct point on the Likert scale, I thought k should take the median of the data in lieu of the mean. So if I ran a rank sum on the medians of the max ratings, so you think that would work? Thank you!

Comment: If the mean of the data is a fair representation of pain, and a difference in means for the 2 cohorts makes sense, that might be better. I haven't seen any of your data, but I'm afraid there might be too many ties among the medians in case you want to use a Wilcoxon test. // You could try medians first, then means, and see which makes the most sense. // Always worried about the calibration of pain scores; subjective and circumstantial--higher scores reported to make sure of enough pain management medication & attention, lower scores reported if patient eager to be released.